# How to normalize IPv6 ip using TCL/Perl?

Tags: python, perl, tcl, ipv6

I want to convert the short format of IPv6 ip into extended format. Lets say I have the ipv6 ip as fe80::1 to fe80:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 and fe80:0010::1 as fe80:0010:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001 and so on. Could you help in writing a script using TCL or Perl or Python language?

The code should be dynamic such a way whatever format I give the expand should be of extended format.

Comment: As a side note, you should accept any valid IPv6 format, but you should always return the compressed format, per [RFC 5952](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5952).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Perl, use the `Net::IP` module:

```
$ perl -MNet::IP=:PROC -le'print ip_expand_address("fe80::1", 6);'
fe80:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001
```

Answer (score 4):

In Tcl, use the `ip` package:

```
% package require ip
1.2.2
% ::ip::normalize fe80::1
fe80:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001
```

Documentation: [ip](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/dns/tcllib_ip.html) package

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible for me to see the source code of ::ip::normalize? I want to see the code flow.

Comment: @user3441116: the source code is [here](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/artifact/f5774de8fef6c790), please note copyright and license terms.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to understand the logic behind this procedure.

Answer (score 3):

For Python, I would suggest using [netaddr](https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to deal with IP addresses of any kind. In your case it has the ability to format IPv6 in different [forms/dialects](https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#ipv6-formatting-dialects).

For your specific use case you should be able to do:

```
import netaddr

ip = netaddr.IPAddress("fe80::1")

print ip.format(dialect=netaddr.ipv6_verbose)
```